# Google sheet : Find-and-replace/remove using formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have `Col A2` -> Contains Reviews
`Col B2` -> contains parasite text

The `Col C2` should be same as `col A2` (Reviews) except that whatever parasite/text in B2 has to be removed from it.

Please look at a sample below.

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The car is good one | one | The car is good |
| A proper place to stay | stay | A proper place to |

Is there a forumla that can achieve this functionality  ?

Comment: Please share more data. The Sheet sample will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=REPLACE(A2,FIND(B2,A2),LEN(B2),"")
```

- `FIND` gives you the starting position of the parasite string in Col A.
- `LEN` gives you the length of the parasite string
- `REPLACE` removes from Col A the parasite string and replaces it with an empty string

Please note that this will not trim whitespace characters (e.g. there is an extra space at the end of Col C).